# Log shipping using SQL Server 2000 Standard edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have one production database on SQL Server 2000 Standard Edition and would like to upgrade it to SQL Server 2005 Standard edition. How to accomplish this task in case of copying transaction log file from source and restore to destination database and making the destination database online also how can I create database user while the destination database is on **NORECOVERY** mode?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks experts

Apologize for my incomplete question and lack of SQL knowledge

I already backed up and restore the production DB on target server with **NORECOVERY** mode while the production server operational (still operational) what I want to do is (if applicable) prepare the target server before I cutover. Now I'm migrating DB objects to target server and once all objects are migrated to target server I'll take the database online by restoring the last log backup if log shipping is applicable in SQL2k standard edition.(my upgrade path is side-by-side)

Thanks all in advance

Comment: easiest method to migrate is to detach the db, copy the .mdf file, reattach, move to the copy to the new server, then attach it there.

Comment: Hi Mark B; Thanks for your help, I just edited my question above to make more clear. our upgrading path is side-by-side and the production DB is still operational, in the meantime, I'm preparing the new server side by side by restoring all DB with NORECOVERY mode that is why I want to use log shipping to restore all transactional log backups to take the DB online at the end of migration. Thanks SO much

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399231/upgrading-from-sql-2000-2008-log-shipping?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what part log shipping plays in your upgrade.

The steps you should take are:

1. Install SQL 2005 on a new server.
2. Take your production system offline.
3. Perform a backup.
4. Restore the backup to the new server.
5. Attach your production system to the new server.
6. Test..test..test.

After you've moved it over, you might consider changing the compatibility level of the database in the new server to SQL 2005.  However, be aware that there are many differences between SQL 2000 and 2005.  So review this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143232(v=sql.90).aspx to get an idea of what issues you might have.

Comment: Hi Chris; Thanks for your help, I just edited my question above to make more clear. our upgrading path is side-by-side and the production DB is still operational, in the meantime, I'm preparing the new server side by side by restoring all DB with NORECOVERY mode that is why I want to use log shipping to restore all transactional log backups to take the DB online at the end of migration. Thanks SO much